# Несколько кнопок в форме обратной связи

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

У меня есть форма, в ней одна кнопка отправки  и две  и несколько полей required.Проблема в чем: две кнопки  не работают, пока не  будут заполнены все обязательные поля, а вот когда они заполнены, форма просто отправляется.Хотя их задача вообще не такая.Как это можно исправить?

Comment: Если бы Вы выложили код, то можно было бы предметней посмотреть.

Comment: Отредактируйте вопрос, из него ничего не понятно и добавьте код

Comment: Хорошо.Сейчас выложу

Comment: Если у кнопок type="button" прописан, то должно работать и внутри тега form

Comment: спасибо, вы помогли

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('[type="submit"]').click((e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log('Прервали отправку');
})
$('[type="button"]').click(() => console.log('Генерируем что-то')
  //тут что-то делаем сами
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="text" name="test">
  <button type="button">Сгенерировать</button>
  <button type="submit">Отправить</button>
</form>
```